# Syntax for making index in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

When i make an index in the rails framework i have write down the table name.
Is there any difference between the following conventions to write the table name.I checked both are working
1)"table_name"
2):table_name

Comment: Even when we create or drop the table both the syntax work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in terms of what it does.

Just symbols versus strings optimisation, nothing to do with ActiveRecord as such.

Comment: Thanks.But suppose i have a login forum and i use a variable to get the parameters and i use the string format can my code be prone to sql injection???

Comment: Symbols are converted to strings to build the sql, so using them does not stop sql injection. Parameterised queries stop that, and they will take symbols or strings, ints and dates as well for that matter..